# Analytic functions theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

There is a result on page 175 in the book 
"All the Mathematics You Missed" by Thomas Garrity.

A complex-valued function $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic at the point $z_{0}=x_{0}+iy_{0}$ if and only if the real valued functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the cauchy Riemann equations at $z_{0}$.

I have counter examples to this result.

$f(x+iy)=\sqrt{\mid x\mid \mid y\mid}$ for all $x,y\in R$. Here $f$ satisfy the cauchy Riemann equation at origin but not holomorphic at origin.

There is an other examples of complex valued function 
$$ f(z)=
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
       \frac{z^5}{\mid z\mid^4} & z\neq 0 \\
      0 & z= 0
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$$
is continuous every where satisfying the cauchy Riemann equations at origin,  but not holomorphic  at origin.

Comment: What's your question? It's well-known that C-R alone is not enough for the function to be holomorphic; see for example the introduction to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations).